# Sequence of numbers per category given first entry (Python, Pandas)

Tags: pandas

Suppose I have 5 categories {A, B, C, D, E} and Several date entries of PURCHASES with distinct dates (for instance, A may range from 01/01/1900 to 31/01/1901 and B from 02/02/1930 to 03/03/1933.

I want to create a new column 'day of occurrence' where I have sequence of number 1...N from the point I find the first date in which number of purchases >= 5.

I want this to compare how categories are similar from the day they've achieved 5 purchases (dates are irrelevant here, but product lifetime is)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can label rows from 1 to N depending on column value.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[3, 6, 9, 3, 6], columns=['data'])
df['day of occurrence'] = 0
values_count = df.loc[df['data'] > 5].shape[0]
df.loc[df['data'] > 5, 'day of occurrence'] = range(1, values_count + 1)
```

The initial `DataFrame`:

```
   data
0     3
1     6
2     9
3     3
4     6
```

Output `DataFrame`:

```
   data  day of occurrence
0     3                  0
1     6                  1
2     9                  2
3     3                  0
4     6                  3
```

Your data should be sorted by date, for example, `df = df.sort_values(by='your-datetime-column')`